# How do i build my angular application with `npm run build : production` instead of using `npm run build --production`?

Tags: angular, npm, deployment, build, npm-run

Hi my angular application is building with the following command:

```
npm run build --production
```

and also it can be built with the following command:

```
npm run build -- --c production
```

But what I want is , I want to build my application with the `:` instead of using `--`
that means I except the same result even I run the below command :

```
npm run build:production
```

Is it possible?

- I have attached my package.json as below:

```
{
  "name": "@coreui/lutosa-obs",
  "version": "0.00.1",
  "description": "Lutosa OBS Portal",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --common-chunk --vendor-chunk --optimization --progress",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "prettier": "prettier --write \"{,!(node_modules|dist|build|coverage)/**/}*.{js,jsx,ts,json}\"",
    "pre-commit": "npm run lint && npm run prettier",
    "extract-i18n": "ngx-translate-extract --input ./src --output ./src/assets/i18n/{en,nl,fr,es,it,de}.json --format namespaced-json --sort"
  },
  "private": true,
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run pre-commit"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^11.1.0",
    "@coreui/angular": "~2.11.1",
    "@coreui/coreui": "^2.1.16",
    "@coreui/coreui-plugin-chartjs-custom-tooltips": "^1.3.1",
    "@coreui/icons": "^2.0.0-rc.0",
    "@coreui/icons-angular": "1.0.0-alpha.3",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@rxweb/reactive-form-validators": "^2.1.2",
    "@uiowa/digit-only": "^2.2.3",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^25.1.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^25.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bs-stepper": "^1.7.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.4",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "cookieconsent": "^3.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "messageformat": "^2.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "ng-lazyload-image": "9.1.0",
    "ngrx-store-localstorage": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-avatar": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^6.2.0",
    "ngx-cookieconsent": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-editor": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
    "ngx-translate-cache": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler": "^4.9.0",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0",
    "primeicons": "^4.1.0",
    "primeng": "^11.2.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.3",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.5.5",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1101.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^11.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.1.0",
    "@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^7.0.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.8",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.22",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "husky": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.5"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 10.13",
    "npm": ">= 6"
  }
}
```

What I need to modify in the scripts section to achieve this. Please help me fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `build:production` command under scripts in your `package.json` file:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
     ...

     "build:production": "ng build --prod --aot --build-optimizer --common-chunk --vendor-chunk --optimization --progress --configuration=production"
   }
}
```

I used the same value you have under `build` command and appended `--configuration=production` to it.

More info: [npm-run-script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script)

Comment: Thank you. I have found it. Now I am facing the npm error

Comment: You're welcome. See my edit. What is the error?